# VBA Find a first row number in a column with numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have a column and i would like to find a first row (from top) which contains numbers ,numbers can be -0.0001 or 10 or 0.123.

Any idea how to write?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

**=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A1:A100),0),0)**

In VBA, if there are just blanks above that first number, then:

```
Sub luxation()
    MsgBox Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
End Sub
```

In VBA, If there is text above that first number, then:

```
Sub NumberSearch()
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "A").Value) And Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: how do i write this in vba

Comment: excellent thanks, it is a 2nd condition i need . i have lots of rows with text.